Mysterious behavior of stack view with a container view in it: items prior to a container don't appear
Start a Mac, open Xcode, create a new swift-storyboard project and paste in the demo code below.
Fire it up and you will see a jiggly scrollable stack something like this ..

All good so far. Let's consider the code HERE:
        indentedInner.backgroundColor = .blue // NOTE
        // now add yellow blocks exactly as with "innerYellow" just above
        for _ in 0..<4 { indentedInner.addArrangedSubview(InBlock()) }

(Notice the indented group is blue tell.)
Now try this!
        indentedInner.backgroundColor = .blue // note
        // now add yellow blocks exactly as with "innerYellow" just above
//        for _ in 0..<4 { indentedInner.addArrangedSubview(InBlock()) }
        // no! don't do that! instead let's add a container view
        let vc = InsideStackOfYellowButInAContainer()
        vc.telltale = .red
        addChild(vc)
        indentedInner.addArrangedSubview(vc.view)
        vc.view.bindEdgesToSuperview()
        vc.didMove(toParent: self)

As you'd expect it works perfectly, the tell is now the red of the container'ed VC, everything still animates, etc.
BUT...
Next, actually let's do BOTH:
    indentedInner.backgroundColor = .blue // note
    // now add yellow blocks exactly as with "innerYellow" just above
    for _ in 0..<4 { indentedInner.addArrangedSubview(InBlock()) }
    // no! don't do that! instead let's add a container view
    // actually let's do both:
    let vc = InsideStackOfYellowButInAContainer()
    vc.telltale = .red
    addChild(vc)
    indentedInner.addArrangedSubview(vc.view)
    vc.view.bindEdgesToSuperview()
    vc.didMove(toParent: self)

I must be making some drastic simple mistake, but, as you will see
the "blue" group plain doesn't appear.
Large letters added for clarity here.
It seems only the red group is present.
I have already tried numerous things like wrappers, every imaginable setting, etc.
Another bizarre "clue", try ALSO adding ...
    for _ in 0..<4 { indentedInner.addArrangedSubview(InBlock()) }
    let L = UILabel()
    L.text = "What the heck"
    indentedInner.addArrangedSubview(L)
    ...

and notice the odd behavior.
I cannot solve the issue after the usual hours of fooling with UIKit.
Why does the blue group not appear?

Demo code ...
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  testsv
//
//  Created by TV'S FATTIE on 10/6/24.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var scroll = UIScrollView.Simp
    var top = UIStackView.Simp
    var innerYellow = UIStackView.Simp
    var indentedInner = UIStackView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(scroll)
        scroll.bindEdgesToSuperview()
        scroll.addSubview(top)
        top.bindEdgesToSuperviewVertScrollStyle()
        for _ in 0..<4 { top.addArrangedSubview(Block()) }
        
        // now make a vert stack with four of the bouncy yellow blocks:
        top.addArrangedSubview(innerYellow)
        for _ in 0..<4 { innerYellow.addArrangedSubview(InBlock()) }
        // works perfectly
        
        // now make a hori group, which has something on the left...
        let hori = UIStackView.HoriWrapper
        // let's try these settings for the hori:
        hori.alignment = .fill
        hori.distribution = .fill
        hori.backgroundColor = .green
        top.addArrangedSubview(hori)
        // here's the something on the left ...
        hori.addArrangedSubview(WidthIndent80())
        // the hori then has a stack precisely like "innerYellow" above
        indentedInner.axis = .vertical
        indentedInner.alignment = .fill // note, or it won't find the height
        indentedInner.distribution = .equalSpacing
        indentedInner.spacing = 8
        indentedInner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // explicitly identical settings to "innerYellow" just above
        hori.addArrangedSubview(indentedInner)
        indentedInner.backgroundColor = .blue // note
        // now add yellow blocks exactly as with "innerYellow" just above
        for _ in 0..<4 { indentedInner.addArrangedSubview(InBlock()) }
        
        // Add more material so the overall always needs to scroll
        for _ in 0..<20 { top.addArrangedSubview(Block()) }
    }
}

class InsideStackOfYellowButInAContainer: UIViewController {
    var telltale: UIColor?
    var innerYellowButInAContainer = UIStackView.Simp
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // obivously
        view.addSubview(innerYellowButInAContainer)
        innerYellowButInAContainer.bindEdgesToSuperview()
        innerYellowButInAContainer.axis = .vertical
        innerYellowButInAContainer.alignment = .fill
        innerYellowButInAContainer.distribution = .equalSpacing
        innerYellowButInAContainer.spacing = 8
        innerYellowButInAContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // explicitly identical settings to "innerYellow" above
        // add yellow blocks exactly as with "innerYellow" above
        for _ in 0..<4 { innerYellowButInAContainer.addArrangedSubview(InBlock()) }
        
        innerYellowButInAContainer.backgroundColor = telltale
    }
}

class Block: UIView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        backgroundColor = .systemPink.jigglingHue()
        var sz = super.intrinsicContentSize
        sz.height = 40
        return sz
    }
}
class InBlock: UIView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        delay(CGFloat.random(in: 3.0...3.5)) {
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
        backgroundColor = .systemYellow.jigglingHue()
        var sz = super.intrinsicContentSize
        sz.height = CGFloat.random(in: 50...100)
        return sz
    }
}
extension UIScrollView {
    static var Simp: UIScrollView {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.bounces = true
        return v
    }
}
extension UIStackView {
    static var Simp: UIStackView {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.alignment = .fill
        v.distribution = .equalSpacing
        v.spacing = 8
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }
}
extension UIStackView {
    static var HoriWrapper: UIStackView {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .horizontal
        v.spacing = 8
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }
}
class WidthIndent80: UIView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        backgroundColor = .lightGray
        var sz = super.intrinsicContentSize
        sz.width = 80
        return sz
    }
}
extension UIView {
    public func bindEdgesToSuperview() {
        guard let s = superview else {
            preconditionFailure("`superview` nil in bindEdgesToSuperview")
        }
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: s.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: s.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: s.topAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: s.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    public func bindEdgesToSuperviewVertScrollStyle() {
        guard let s = superview else {
            preconditionFailure("`superview` nil in bindEdgesToSuperview")
        }
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: s.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: s.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: s.topAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: s.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: s.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    public func bindTopToSuperview() {
        guard let s = superview else {
            preconditionFailure("`superview` nil in bindEdgesToSuperview")
        }
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: s.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: s.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: s.topAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
extension UIColor {
    func jigglingHue() -> UIColor {
        var h: CGFloat = 0, s: CGFloat = 0, b: CGFloat = 0, a: CGFloat = 0
        guard self.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &b, alpha: &a) else { return self }
        var jiggle = h + CGFloat.random(in: -0.04...0.04)
        while jiggle < 0 { jiggle += 1.0 }
        while jiggle >= 1 { jiggle -= 1.0 }
        return UIColor(hue: jiggle, saturation: s, brightness: b, alpha: a)
    }
}
public func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping () -> ()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}


It needs MORE CLARITY?  Can you explain yourself ?

Remove this line vc.view.bindEdgesToSuperview().
This creates extra constraints and makes some of the subViews disappear

Ah, bingo!  You're right, Immanuel!  I previously had it in a wrapper and that was left-over code.  Good call!
